# flexbox align-self with nth-child issue

Tags: flexbox, css-selectors

I am trying to play around with flexbox align-self on the flex-items.
This is my markup:

```
<div class="PortfolioItem">
    <div class="PortfolioItem__textBox">
      <h1>We have a green light</h1>
      <h2>We have a go</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="PortfolioItem">
    <div class="PortfolioItem__textBox">
      <h1>We have a green light</h1>
      <h2>We have a go</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and this is my css:

```
.PortfolioItem{
  display: flex;

  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.PortfolioItem__textBox:nth-child(odd){
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.PortfolioItem__textBox:nth-child(even){
  align-self: flex-end;
  text-align: right;
}
```

When I check this in the property inspector, the nth-child part is never read.
What have I missed out?

ThanksI

Answer (score 0):

changed the css to the following:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* Flex Container */
.app {
    display: flex;

    background: #def;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

/* Flex Items */
.PortfolioItem__textBox {
    color: black;
}

.PortfolioItem{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50vw;
}

.PortfolioItem:nth-child(odd) {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

.PortfolioItem:nth-child(even) {
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```